# Call and run php script from shell script

Tags: bash, scripts, php

I'm trying something simple yet can't figured it out. Trying to run one shell script which call php script from the site directory. My shell script is simple `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

LIST="/path/to/my/site/dir"
CONFIG="/usr/bin/php "

for i in $LIST
do
    . "${CONFIG}${i}/test.php"        
done
```

My `test.php` doesn't have errors and when I run it directly in browser it's working. It again simple script like

```
<?php
  // source code
?>
```

When I run `./test.sh` result is

> ./test.sh: 8: .: Can't open /usr/bin/php /path/to/my/site/dir/test.php

Line 8 is `. "${CONFIG}${i}/test.php"`

I've tried also to add at the beginning of PHP file this line but the result is same

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

UPDATE: Path to php

```
$ which -a php
/usr/bin/php
```

I've also made `chmod +x test.php`

Comment: Try to append the `-q`, like this: `/usr/bin/php -q /path/to/my/site/dir/test.php`

Comment: Thanks but same `./test.sh: 8: .: Can't open /usr/bin/php -q /path/to/my/site/dir/test.php`

Comment: Ok, please try with the `-f` (Parse and execute file) like this: `php -f test.php` . make sure the file is executable `chmod +x test.php`

Comment: When I run `$ php /path/to/test.php` directly in terminal it's working. But from shell script doesn't work

Comment: Please remove the quote marks and the dot in line 8. Check the update of my answer.

Comment: Without them I've got 1000+ lines in terminal with mysql/php configuration files..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you are quoting the entiore command you are trying to run as a single variable. As a result, you're not running `php` with `foo.php` as an argument but instead are attempting to execute a file called `php foo.php`. Here's a simpler example to show you what I mean:

```
$ var1="echo "
$ var2="foo"
$ set -x ## debugging info
$ "$var1$var2"
+ 'echo foo'      ### The shell tries to execute both vars as a single command
bash: echo foo: command not found

$ "$var1" "$var2"
+ 'echo ' foo     ### The shell tries to execute 'echo ' (echo with a space)
bash: echo foo: command not found
```

So, the right way is to remove the space and quote each variable separately:

```
$ var1="echo"
$ var2="foo"
$ "$var1" "$var2"
```

If you do that though, you'll hit the next error. The `.` is the [`source` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot). That tries to read a *shell* script and execute it in the current session. You are giving it a php script instead. That won't work, you need to *execute* it, not *source* it.

Finally, always avoid using CAPITAL variable names. The shell's reserved variables are capitalized so it's a good idea to always use lower case variable names for your scripts.

Putting all this together (with a few other minor improvements), what you want is something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

list="/path/to/my/site/dir"
config="/usr/bin/php"

for i in "$list"
do
    "$config" "$i"/test.php
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining and helped to get this script work!

Answer (score 5):

The problem in your code is the line:

```
. "${CONFIG}${i}/test.php"
```

Remove the `.`

---

Here is another example:

**$ ls -l**

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 bg bg 67 Oct 20 09:42 index.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 bg bg 68 Oct 20 09:43 test.sh
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    shell_exec('echo Hello > /tmp/hello.txt');
?>
```

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/php index.php
```

Comment: Hm may be because of different users? `-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 382 Oct 20 09:46 test.sh` and `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root www-data   25 Aug 19 09:15 test.php` ?

Comment: I've tried it already and the result is `/test.sh: line 8: /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/site/test.php: No such file or directory`

Comment: with #!/bin/sh -> ./test.sh: line 8: /usr/bin/php /path/to/my/site/dir/test.php: not found

Comment: Make sure you set `/path/to/my/site/dir/` to your real correct path

Comment: I'm sure it's correct `$ pwd -> /var/www/html/site`

Answer (score 3):

Usually the command php is used for interpretation of PHP scripts in the shell.

```
$ php /path/script-name.php
```

I made simple test.sh and it works:

```
$ cat ./text.sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo php /var/www/wiki/maintenance/update.php

$ chmod +x ./test.sh
$ ./test.sh
```

It works.

After that I made complicated script as your example:

```
$ cat ./text.sh

#!/bin/sh

LIST=/var/www/wiki/maintenance
CONFIG=/usr/bin/php

for i in $LIST
do
    ${CONFIG} ${i}/update.php
done

$ sudo ./test.sh
```

It works!

```
$ cat ./text.sh

#!/bin/sh

LIST="/var/www/wiki/maintenance"
CONFIG="/usr/bin/php "

for i in $LIST
do
    ${CONFIG}${i}/update.php
done

$ sudo ./test.sh
```

Works also!

Comment: same `./test.sh: 8: .: Can't open php /path/to/my/site/dir/test.php`

Comment: When I run `$ php /path/script-name.php` directly in terminal it's working. But from shell script doesn't work

Comment: Have you try run it as bash script `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: You mean `#!/bin/bash php /path/to/test.php` ?

Comment: I mean to put it in the first line of the script instead of `#!/bin/sh`. This line indicates the shell who will interpret the script.

Comment: Hm, different error now. Like the file isn't in the directory but it is `./test.sh: line 8: .: /usr/bin/php /path/to/my/site/dir/test.php: No such file or directory`

Comment: I've wrote full path there like `/var/www/html/site/test.php`

Comment: However, `#!/bin/sh` isn't a problem. I think @Benny is right, remove `.`.

Comment: with `#!/bin/sh` -> `./test.sh: line 8: /usr/bin/php /path/to/my/site/dir/test.php: not found`

Comment: Still I've got `Not found` and without quote marks I've got 1000+ lines in terminal with mysql/php configuration files.. Everything is same as your and Benny's examples and didn't work.

Comment: When I run `$ php /path/to/script/test.php` directly in terminal it's work. But if I run same thing from shell script which contain same lines I've got `not found`.  Even your first example `#!/bin/bash sudo php /var/www/wiki/maintenance/update.php`

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`? That just introduces a pointless security problem. Please only use `sudo` when you need it.

Comment: Just for testing @SpasSpasov examples. Still doesn't want to execute php script from shell script. It's executed only if I run it directly in terminal

Comment: @S.I. yes, it won't. See my answer. You need to i) remove the extra space from `CONFIG`; ii) quote the variables separately and iii) execute it, not source it.