# Cron is executed but script doesn't work

Tags: scripts, php, cron

I know there are a lot of similar question and I've tried lots of things but still can't make it work.

I have cronjob which is scheduled to run on 10min. I can see in `/var/log/syslog` that it is run normally

```
Oct 21 07:30:01 stan CRON[7604]: (stan) CMD (stan /home/stan/update.sh)
Oct 21 07:40:01 stan CRON[8304]: (stan) CMD (stan /home/stan/update.sh)
Oct 21 07:50:01 stan CRON[8751]: (stan) CMD (stan /home/stan/update.sh)
Oct 21 08:00:01 stan CRON[9347]: (stan) CMD (stan /home/stan/update.sh)
Oct 21 08:10:01 stan CRON[9789]: (stan) CMD (stan /home/stan/update.sh)
```

`update.sh` call `php` script which update database. When I run directly from terminal the shell script database got updated and it's working perfectly

```
./update.sh
```

But from cronjob doesn't update database. My cron

```
*/10 * * * * stan /home/stan/update.sh
```

Command produced from shell script is

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/site/update.php
```

Permissions of both files

```
-rwxrwxr-x  1 stan stan    123 Oct 20 15:09 update.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 stan www-data 1301 Oct 21 07:52 /var/www/html/site/update.php
```

Any idea what can be the problem?

Update: PATH

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

`update.sh`

```
$ cat update.sh
```

```sh
#!/bin/sh

list="/var/www/html/site"
config="/usr/bin/php"

for i in "$list"
do
    "$config" "$i"/update.php
done
```

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839499/call-and-run-php-script-from-shell-script) my question from yesterday which was about the shell and php now is about cron.

```
$ whereis php

php: /usr/bin/php5.6 /usr/bin/php /usr/lib/php /etc/php /usr/include/php /usr/share/php5.6-intl /usr/share/php7.0-mbstring /usr/share/php7.0-common /usr/share/php5.6-curl /usr/share/php5.6-gd /usr/share/php5.6-mcrypt /usr/share/php5.6-common /usr/share/php5.6-readline /usr/share/php5.6-json /usr/share/php /usr/share/php5.5-mbstring /usr/share/php5.6-opcache /usr/share/php5.6-mbstring /usr/share/php5.6-xml /usr/share/php5.5-common /usr/share/php5.6-mysql /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

---

```
$ which php
/usr/bin/php
```

Comment: Is this a user crontab, or a file in /etc/cron.d? You appear to be using the format of the latter (with an additional `user` field) within the former - hence your log shows that it is trying to run a *command* `stan` with *argument* `/home/stan/update.sh`

Comment: user `stan` yes.  I'm logged with this user `$ who ->
stan     tty7         2016-10-21 06:54 (:0)
`

Comment: So you created the job using `crontab -e` rather than creating a file in `/etc/cron.d`?

Comment: Yes, via `crontab -e`

Comment: Well, I've removed `stan` from `crontab -e` and seems to work now. Why isn't work with the user? And in this case how can I tell which cron for which user is?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be confusing two different methods of invoking `cron` jobs.

Ubuntu inherits from Debian a somewhat confusing policy of supporting both user `crontabs` that are stored in a spool area `/var/spool/cron`, and system-wide cron jobs run from `/etc/crontab` and the files in `/etc/cron.d`.

Jobs specified in `/etc/crontab` or via files in `/etc/cron.d` need an extra field in order to allow them to be run as a different user so the format is something like

```
*/10 * * * * <username> <command> <args>
```

Jobs set up via the spool area using `crontab -e` (or `sudo crontab -e` for root) already belong to a specific user, and don't need the user field

```
*/10 * * * * <command> <args>
```

If you include the username field in a cron job set up via a `crontab -e` command, it will be misinterpreted as a command: as we can see from your log output,

```
Oct 21 07:30:01 stan CRON[7604]: (stan) CMD (stan /home/stan/update.sh)
```

`cron` is interpreting `stan` as a *command* with *argument* `/home/stan/update.sh`

The solution should be simply to remove the username `stan` from your crontab.

Comment: Thank you for the help and for making clear those two methods.

Answer (score 2):

a few possible problems:

1) You may not have `#!/bin/sh` as a first line in `update.sh`

2) PHP may need to execute extra commands but cron jobs are executed without the PATH variable being set. To fix that use `echo $PATH` on the terminal where the command works and then use `export PATH=...`, replacing the `...` with the output of `echo $PATH` above

3) PHP may need other environment variables to function. Track them down and export them in `update.sh` prior to calling `/usr/bin/php`.

**Edit**

OK, it isn't 1)

Open a new window (or a new ssh connection) and execute:

```
for i in `env | sed 's/=.*//'` ; do unset $i ; done
```

This will unset all environment variables, including the PATH. Then try:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/site/update.php
```

Then post here the error messages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've updated my question. As you see `1) and 2)` are fine. I'm not sure what you mean in `3)`?

Comment: Just a question before I unset them. I will need to set them again later? And btw why I need to test this since the script is working when I run it directly like this in terminal?

Comment: You will unset them just for the current shell session. That is why I asked you to open a new window. Once you are done just type `exit`, the terminal window will close and everything will be back to normal.

Comment: Done. I've unset them. Then executed `/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/site/update.php` and database got updated.  `echo $PATH` is empty. No errors at all and script is working.

Comment: OK, so it is neither 2) nor 3). Your problem is somewhere else and I have no idea where. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the very limited path variable search of crontab.  Full path has to be added to add to almost all your commands in all your scripts and subscripts.  Or you can add the same search path to the script that you have when running the script manually.

**Change from:**

```bash
#!/bin/sh

list="/var/www/html/site"
config="/usr/bin/php"

for i in "$list"
do
    "$config" "$i"/update.php
done
```

**Change to:**

```bash
#!/bin/sh

PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

list="/var/www/html/site"
config="/usr/bin/php"

for i in "$list"
do
    "$config" "$i"/update.php
done
```

**Note**:

*The added path search was taken from what you posted in your question, which work when running the script manually.  If you know which path contains the command from the script along with any script or command called by the `update.php` script, then those are the only search paths that needs to be added.*

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to add `PATH` in the `for` now? because still doesn't update database

Comment: No.  Just add the one line in the `change to` block.

Comment: Added and cron still run on 10min and still didn't update. I've added what `whereis php` return in terminal to my question if is in help also...